# Common NSURLCONNECTION Failure Reasons

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate

Is there any ways to systematically display the errors when did fail delegate is called in NSURLConnection delegate method?Is there any helper methods to find the associated error with error number returned by the delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about `NSError` in Apple's documentation. It has certain properties and methods to give details of error/failures. Once you're good with this you can access the error object provided    in the delegate method to know about the NSURLConnection failure.

Also, you can use  `object.description` or `object.debugDescription`

If you want to see the common errors (i.e. understandable by laymen ), then just print `error.localizedDescription`. It will print something very simple as "Internet not available" etc. instead of giving you error codes, etc.

Comment: I need to print custom error message with the type of associated message,but as i see the list of errors are so large to be used inside  switch statement.@

CodenameLambda1 Can you suggest the common errors?

Comment: Yes, if you want to see the common errors (i.e. understandable by laymen ), then just print error.localizedDescription. It will print something very simple as "Internet not available" etc. instead of giving you error codes, etc.

Comment: I need to take actions based on connectivity problems such as wi-fi not available or download failure,authentication failed etc...